# How Do I Add A Newline In-between Information?

Tags: php, html

I am attempting to get the information from a single row of a MySQL database using PHP and MySQLi. My current code is

```
    $getQuery = "SELECT row FROM table";
    $query = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    if ($query) {
        while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
            $contents = implode("\n", $row);
            echo $contents;
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Error!';
    }
```

But when I echo `$contents` it will return

```
Data1Data2Data3
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Use "<br />" instead of "\n"

Comment: That implode will work to put a `\n` between columns and that query has one column. Merge all row and use implode on all of them or `echo $row['row']."\n"`

Comment: @JuanEizmendi When I try to use `echo $row['row']."\n";` it gives me `Undefined index: row` error. How do I fix this or how do I merge them all into one row and implode them?

Comment: i use `row` as a key because it's in the query(maybe the query was an example), `echo implode(",",$row)."\n";` that will join all columns with a `,` and add a new line.

Answer (score 0):

HTML recognises the newline character as any other whitespace, it will at most produce a space character in the resulting page. You should use `<br>` instead.

```php
implode("<br>", $row);
```